# htaccess redirect with wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I've looked at other answers to similar questions, but don't know enough about perl and htaccess to modify them.

Google keeps trying to find translated pages from a long-ago and failed experiment with a Google Translate plugin on a WordPress site. The 404s it finds obscure "real" 404s that I try to fix.

I need to redirect from

```
www.domain.com/xx/year/month/slug
```

to

```
www.domain.com/year/month/slug
```

and make it a permanent redirect. xx can be any two lower-case letters.

Can anyone help me with what I need to put in htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z][a-z](/.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Sorry, I wasn't clear, but year/month/slug vary from one URL to another. So I guess I'm looking to have those be a variable. Would that be ^[a-z][a-z] $1 [R=301,l]?

Comment: Ah, OK. I've just modified my answer accordingly.